# Implementing Fuzzy Dates

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Trying to output a fuzzy date from the following function:

```
import Foundation

let kMinute = 60
let kDay = kMinute * 24
let kWeek = kDay * 7
let kMonth = kDay * 31
let kYear = kDay * 365

func NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(key: String) -> String {

    let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath
    let path = resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("NSDateTimeAgo.bundle")
    let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)

    return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "NSDateTimeAgo", bundle: bundle!, comment: "")
}

extension NSDate {

    // shows 1 or two letter abbreviation for units.
    // does not include 'ago' text ... just {value}{unit-abbreviation}
    // does not include interim summary options such as 'Just now'
    var timeAgoSimple: String {

        let now = NSDate()
        let deltaSeconds = Int(fabs(timeIntervalSinceDate(now)))
        let deltaMinutes = deltaSeconds / 60

        var value: Int!

        if deltaSeconds < kMinute {
            // Seconds
            return stringFromFormat("%%d%@s", withValue: deltaSeconds)
        } else if deltaMinutes < kMinute {
            // Minutes
            return stringFromFormat("%%d%@m", withValue: deltaMinutes)
        } else if deltaMinutes < kDay {
            // Hours
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kMinute)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d%@h", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < kWeek {
            // Days
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kDay)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d%@d", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < kMonth {
            // Weeks
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kWeek)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d%@w", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < kYear {
            // Month
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kMonth)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d%@mo", withValue: value)
        }

        // Years
        value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kYear)))
        return stringFromFormat("%%d%@yr", withValue: value)
    }

    var timeAgo: String {

        let now = NSDate()
        let deltaSeconds = Int(fabs(timeIntervalSinceDate(now)))
        let deltaMinutes = deltaSeconds / 60

        var value: Int!

        if deltaSeconds < 5 {
            // Just Now
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("Just now")
        } else if deltaSeconds < kMinute {
            // Seconds Ago
            return stringFromFormat("%%d %@seconds ago", withValue: deltaSeconds)
        } else if deltaSeconds < 120 {
            // A Minute Ago
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("A minute ago")
        } else if deltaMinutes < kMinute {
            // Minutes Ago
            return stringFromFormat("%%d %@minutes ago", withValue: deltaMinutes)
        } else if deltaMinutes < 120 {
            // An Hour Ago
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("An hour ago")
        } else if deltaMinutes < kDay {
            // Hours Ago
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kMinute)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d %@hours ago", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < (kDay * 2) {
            // Yesterday
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("Yesterday")
        } else if deltaMinutes < kWeek {
            // Days Ago
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kDay)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d %@days ago", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < (kWeek * 2) {
            // Last Week
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("Last week")
        } else if deltaMinutes < kMonth {
            // Weeks Ago
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kWeek)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d %@weeks ago", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < (kDay * 61) {
            // Last month
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("Last month")
        } else if deltaMinutes < kYear {
            // Month Ago
            value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kMonth)))
            return stringFromFormat("%%d %@months ago", withValue: value)
        } else if deltaMinutes < (kDay * (kYear * 2)) {
            // Last Year
            return NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings("Last Year")
        }

        // Years Ago
        value = Int(floor(Float(deltaMinutes / kYear)))
        return stringFromFormat("%%d %@years ago", withValue: value)

    }

    func stringFromFormat(format: String, withValue value: Int) -> String {

        let localeFormat = String(format: format, getLocaleFormatUnderscoresWithValue(Double(value)))

        return String(format: NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(localeFormat), value)
    }

    func getLocaleFormatUnderscoresWithValue(value: Double) -> String {

        let localeCode = NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first as String

        if localeCode == "fr" {
            let XY = Int(floor(value)) % 100
            let Y = Int(floor(value)) % 10

            if Y == 0 || Y > 4 || (XY > 10 && XY < 15) {
                return ""
            }

            if Y > 1 && Y < 5 && (XY < 10 || XY > 20) {
                return "_"
            }

            if Y == 1 && XY != 11 {
                return "__"
            }
        }

        return ""
    }

}
```

Now when calling the function like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fuzzyDate: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var dateNow = "Jan 17, 2015, 3:31 AM"

        fuzzyDate.text = NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(dateNow)
    }

}
```

The result is "Jan 17, 2015, 3:31 AM" instead of "xx hours ago".  What am I doing incorrectly?  Newbie here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
var dateNow = "Jan 17, 2015, 3:31 AM"
fuzzyDate.text = NSDateTimeAgoLocalizedStrings(dateNow)
```

does nowhere call the `timeAgo` method which you defined.
It only localizes the given string, without any date or time calculation.

You have to convert the `String` "Jan 17, 2015, 3:31 AM" to
an `NSDate` first, using a *date formatter*:

```
var dateNow = "Jan 17, 2015, 3:31 AM"
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a"
let date = fmt.dateFromString(dateNow)!
```

and then you can apply the `timeAgo` method to that date to
get the "fuzzy string":

```
fuzzyDate.text = date.timeAgo // Result: 8 hours ago
```

---

*Remark:* All date and time calculations that exceed the range of hours
should better be done using `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponent` methods,
instead of "simply" dividing by 60, 24, 7, 31 or 365.
The reason is that there are days with 23 or 25 hours (daylight saving
time transitions), so that not every day has 24*60*60 seconds.
Also not every month has 31 days, and a year may have 356 or 366 days.